# click() apply on image to change video in display div

Tags: jquery

hello i want to make a youtube playlist like interface i have tried following code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.video_display').html('<iframe width="388" height="263" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/qK0w8PmpA8Q" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>);

    $('#img1').click(function(){
        $('.video_display').html('<iframe width="388" height="293" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/nfjD9Kz8DDY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');

        })
})


</script>
```

Html

```
<ul>    

     <li id="img1"><img src="images/footer_img.jpg" alt=" " /></li>
     <li id="img2"><img src="images/footer_img.jpg" alt=" " /></li>
     <li id="img3"><img src="images/footer_img.jpg" alt=" " /></li>
     <li id="img4"><img src="images/footer_img.jpg" alt=" " /></li>
     <li id="img5"><img src="images/footer_img.jpg" alt=" " /></li>
     <li id="img6"><img src="images/footer_img.jpg" alt=" " /></li>
     <li id="img7"><img src="images/footer_img.jpg" alt=" " /></li>

</ul>
```

my script is not working plz help

Thanks

Comment: What exactly does *not working* mean in this case?

Comment: please post your full code, there is no element with a class of `video_display` in your code !

Comment: you are missing a `'` in your code! `.html(')`

Comment: errrr .... thanks Roko C.buljan there's missing a ' in my code . now its working thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yep; you are missing a closing quote: jsfiddle here: **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/ghqby/11/

try this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.video_display').html('<iframe width="388" height="263" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/qK0w8PmpA8Q" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');

    $('#img1').click(function(){
        $('.video_display').html('<iframe width="388" height="293" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/nfjD9Kz8DDY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');

        })
})


</script>
```

This will help, cheers!